# How can I manage multiple administrators with juju?

Tags: juju

I manage some deployments with juju. However I am not an island, I have coworkers who also want to manage shared environments.

I know I can use the following stanza in `~/.juju/environments.yaml` to give people access to my juju environment:

```
authorized-keys: [and then put their ssh IDs in here]
```

What other best practices are available to manage multiple environments with multiple system administrators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juju is really not at this time optimized for multiple admins. In
particular, some of the [security issues](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bugs?field.tag=security) that are currently seen in
Juju become more pronounced when working with multiple
admins. However, with some caveats, this can still remain a useful
option for a trusted - and thus likely small - group of admins.

With that in mind, let's look at the relevant configuration
items in the `~/.juju/environment.yaml` file.

The `authorized-keys` item is used in the environment bootstrap to
define the public SSH keys for the ubuntu user on the bootstrap node
(machine 0, on which ZooKeeper runs) and all subsequently provisioned
nodes. Simply list authorized one public key per line. It will look
like the following:

```
authorized-keys: |
    ssh-rsa AAAblahblahZZZZ user@domain
    ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAfoobarZZZZ= user2@domain
```

This approach is preferrable to using `authorized-keys-path` - or its
default (`~/.ssh/`) - which is only suitable for one admin, given that
you would then have to share SSH keys (don't do that!). Simply put,
this is just a limitation of how `authorized-keys-path` is
implemented.

Next, cloud providers define their specific security credentials,
which Juju then uses. By way of example, let's take a look at EC2,
specifically AWS. For AWS two keys are used to determine access:
`access-key` and `secret-key`, corresponding to environment variables
`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` (these are the
defaults if not specified in the config file). The challenge here for
a multiple admin environment - or even the single admin environment -
is that this information is copied to ZooKeeper and is readily visible
in the ZK node `/environment`. See Juju [bug #907094](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/907094).

In the AWS example, some degree of control can be provided on your
access keys through the use of AWS Identity and Access Management FAQ
(search for this), but currently there is no mechanism to provide more
fine-grained control to a given admin in a Juju environment.

One additional pattern seen in our own usage, especially in testing,
is worth noting: a Juju environment ("control") set up on a given node
to control other Juju environments; simply deploy the [juju charm](http://jujucharms.com/charms/precise/juju)
to have this set up. It takes as a config option the
`environment.yaml` to be used. Additional admins can then be later
authorized as the `ubuntu` user by manually adding their keys to
`~ubuntu/.ssh/authorized-keys`.

This allows for a single point to manage some of these concerns, while
minimizing the headache. It does nothing to address some of the
security concerns mentioned earlier - you still must have a reasonably
deep trust of your other admins.

Juju will resync `environments.yaml` to the ZK node `/environment` upon
the use of certain commands (`juju add-unit`, `juju constraints-get`,
`juju constraints-set`, `juju deploy`, `juju terminate-machine`). In
practice, this will not be terribly useful - except for its real
intended usage, of supporting constraints. However, it can help
minimize the need to update authorized-keys files as any newly
provisioned machines after the sync will get that; you would then just
be responsible for updating earlier provisioned machines.

While I'm on this point, it is worth noting how and where in
 `~ubuntu/.ssh/authorized-keys` are actually used:

- All Juju control commands, with two exceptions, use a SSH tunnel to
  the ZooKeepeer instance to manage or lookup info from the Juju
  environment. (`juju bootstrap` and `juju destroy-environment`
  directly work with the underlying cloud provider API.)  So you
  definitely need to keep the `authorized-keys` on machine 0 current.
- `juju ssh` and `juju scp` enable working with a machine directly,
  and they also need to have current `authorized-keys` that you will
  have to consider updating in the multiple admin case. These
  commands by default use the `ubuntu` user on the target machine.